# Where to store an Ontology data for queries?

Tags: node.js, rdf, owl, ontology, triplestore

I have a Node.JS app that should perform some queries on my ontology. The ontology was created using protegé and there's some data on it.

The problem is I do not know where / how to create this triple store making it a SPARQL endpoint.

As I did not find anything, at least recent, by googling, I suppose I am completely lost.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want to install proper SPARQL endpoint, you could try something like https://github.com/beautifulinteractions/node-quadstore. Otherwise, https://github.com/search?q=node.js+sparql

Comment: You could also use the free or community edition of a more robust RDF database such as [Stardog Community](https://www.stardog.com/) or Ontotext [GraphDB Free](https://ontotext.com/products/graphdb/).